# Classes of compact spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Given a class $\mathcal{C}$ of compact Hausdorff spaces which is closed under countable products and continuous images. Let $\kappa>\omega$ be a cardinal number. Consider the class $\mathcal{C}^\prime$ consisting of compact spaces produced by taking products of less than $\kappa$ spaces from the class $\mathcal{C}$. Must the class $\mathcal{C}^\prime$ be closed under continuous images?

Comment: Any concrete examples where the hypothesis holds?